# How do I pay taxes on earnings from the sale of my Android app?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, small-business

I'm under 18, so right now I don't pay any taxes. I had a paid app and I also just started advertising, so eventually I may be making income. I don't want to be evading taxes, so I want to know how to go about paying them. I know that both Google Wallet Merchant Center and Admob put my Social Security number on a tax form, so will I just be notified by them when taxes are due? Or do I need to create an LLC or SP?

Answer (score 5):

> Lets say i'm under 18, so right now i don't pay taxes

What's the connection? The fact that you're minor doesn't make you "tax exempt", you pay taxes just as anyone else.

> i want to know how to go about paying them

You, or your parents, file tax returns on your behalf and pay your taxes. If any are due, that is.

> will i just be notified by them when there due?

No, its your responsibility. They might send you some tax forms (1099), but even if they don't - your taxes are your responsibility. The IRS has [detailed instructions](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040/ar01.html#d0e385) on who and when has to file tax returns.

> Or do i need to create a LLC?

These are legal entities for limiting liability. In most cases they won't add any tax benefits, and in fact may cost more in taxes (especially in California).

Comment: An important point from your link is that minors with earned income under $5,900 (and unearned income under $950) don't have to file a tax return.